# cosine similarity built-in function in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, cosine-similarity

I want to calculate cosine similarity between different rows of a matrix in matlab. I wrote the following code in matlab:

```
for i = 1:n_row
    for j = i:n_row
        S2(i,j) = dot(S1(i,:), S1(j,:)) / (norm_r(i) * norm_r(j));
        S2(j,i) = S2(i,j);
```

matrix S1 is 11000*11000 and the code execution is very time consuming. So, I want to know Is there any function in matlab to calculate the cosine similarity between matrix rows faster than the above code?

Comment: I think you are looking for `S2 = 1 - pdist(S1, 'cosine')` , https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html

Comment: `S2 = 1 - pdist(S1, 'cosine')` returns one number while i need a n-by-n matrix that each element of it holds `S2(i,j) =dot(S1(i,:), S1(j,:)) / (norm_r(i) * norm_r(j))`

Comment: What is `norm_r`?

Comment: @Cris Luengo `norm_r = sqrt(sum(abs(S1).^2,2));
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code loops over all rows, and for each row loops over (about) half the rows, computing the dot product for each unique combination of rows:

```
n_row = size(S1,1);
norm_r = sqrt(sum(abs(S1).^2,2)); % same as norm(S1,2,'rows')
S2 = zeros(n_row,n_row);
for i = 1:n_row
  for j = i:n_row
    S2(i,j) = dot(S1(i,:), S1(j,:)) / (norm_r(i) * norm_r(j));
    S2(j,i) = S2(i,j);
  end
end
```

(I've taken the liberty to complete your code so it actually runs. Note the initialization of `S2` before the loop, this saves a lot of time!)

If you note that the dot product is a matrix product of a row vector with a column vector, you can see that the above, without the normalization step, is identical to

```
S2 = S1 * S1.';
```

This runs much faster than the explicit loop, even if it is (maybe?) not able to use the symmetry. The normalization is simply dividing each row by `norm_r` and each column by `norm_r`. Here I multiply the two vectors to produce a square matrix to normalize with:

```
S2 = (S1 * S1.') ./ (norm_r * norm_r.');
```

Answer (score 8):

Short version by calculating the similarity with [`pdist`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html):

```
S2 = squareform(1-pdist(S1,'cosine')) + eye(size(S1,1));
```

#### Explanation:

`pdist(S1,'cosine')` calculates the cosine distance between all combinations of rows in `S1`. Therefore the similarity between all combinations is `1 - pdist(S1,'cosine')` .

We can turn that into a square matrix where element `(i,j)` corresponds to the similarity between rows `i` and `j` with `squareform(1-pdist(S1,'cosine'))`.

Finally we have to set the main diagonal to 1 because the similaritiy of a row with itself is obviously 1 but that is not explicitly calculated by `pdist`.

Comment: There's a `pdist2` function that returns exactly this square matrix.